# Why is 12.04.1 download so horrendously slow?

Tags: installation, windows-7

I tried to install Ubuntu side by side with windows but got problem with Disk image could not be found. I even donated!

So i went to download the CD and to install off-line...

and now have been sitting on my thumbs for 1hr and 100 of 690 MB...

Comment: Release day=slow servers, have some *patience*

Comment: No need to hammer Lewis with negatives for this question.  A newcomer will be understandably peeved and frustrated when they try to download right now.  I think it's valid question and should be left alone, or answered with a possible solution.

Comment: Had this issue today, using mint instead if ubuntu can't maintain their own mirrors or give you different options for the iso download

Answer (score 6):

Quantal Quetzal 12.10 has just been released.  The servers are being *hammered*.

I suggest you try a [bitTorrent download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads).

I've been getting my iso images through the official bitTorrent for a few years now, for several reasons:

1. Packets are fully verified and fixed if faulty.  I haven't had a bad md5sum since I started using this method (had a couple of expensive dud downloads prior to that though)
2. It's quicker than downloading directly at times like now, when many thousands of people are all trying to get a new release.
3. You can re-seed the iso if you want.  I normally reseed at least 10:1 and in fact I have the 32 and 64 bit releases of 10.04.1 sitting idle but ready for anyone who wants a few blocks.